# Prevent body scrolling when a fixed div is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a fixed slide menu that appears only on mobiles , the problem I got is , when I touch scroll down the menu, all the body elements scrolls down too,I want to prevent body scrolling when touch scrolling the nav element, I tried many js codes but nothing, Help please. 
PS: The Menu I want to scroll is inside the body, I dont want to prevent it from scrolling too

Comment: Please include the bare minimum HTML, CSS, and Javascript in your question.

Answer (score -1):

First thing would be make the menu big enough that it needs to be scrolled, so, let's say your menu wrapper has a height of 200px. The inner content should have more than 200px, at least.

After that you can add overflow-y: scroll; to your menu wrapper CSS selector.

If you face problems, http://iscrolljs.com should help you with that!

Comment: the menu is scrollable, thats not the problem,  the problem is that the body scrolls with the menu is being scrolled

Comment: Well, then using the lib would be a great choice - at least it's what I used in the products I had developed. Anyway, if you have a link, perhaps I can understand the problem better.